# split long string inside one list to small lists

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

How do you split this long string of one list to small multi-lists as show on the output  ? (I have file has 100 lines)

```
Num=['S', 'I', 'R', 'T', 'S', 'A', 'V', 'P', 'S', 'P', 'C', 'G', 'K', 'Y', 'Y', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'G', 'S', 'K', '\n', ',', 'S', 'T', 'P', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'K', 'V', 'K', 'A', 'S', 'G', 'M', 'K', 'A', 'I', 'M', 'M', 'A', '\n']
```

Output should look like this:

```
['S', 'I', 'R', 'T', 'S', 'A', 'V', 'P', 'S', 'P', 'K', 'G', 'K', 'Y', 'Y', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'G', 'S', 'K']

['S', 'T', 'P', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'K', 'V', 'K', 'A', 'S', 'G', 'M', 'K', 'A', 'I', 'M', 'M', 'A']
```

Comment: If your list only contains one-character strings, wouldn't it make more sense to keep your strings as a `string` rather than a `list`? Both are iterable.

Answer (score 1):

First `join` the elements, `strip()` leading-trailing whitespace characters, `split` on a new line `\n` and comma `,` and then map them to a list again.

In short:

```
l1, l2 = map(list, "".join(Num).strip().split('\n,'))
```

Now, `l1, l2` look, respectively:

```
['S', 'I', 'R', 'T', 'S', 'A', 'V', 'P', 'S', 'P', 'C', 'G', 'K', 'Y', 'Y', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'G', 'S', 'K']
```

and

```
['S', 'T', 'P', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'K', 'V', 'K', 'A', 'S', 'G', 'M', 'K', 'A', 'I', 'M', 'M', 'A']
```